# While loop endless cycle (2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm currently quite new to Python, just a heads up.

I've been working on a multichoice quiz, and it seems like with every improvement I make, the more problems pop up. This is a snip from the quiz itself. The issue is that whenever I run this code, the while loop continues to repeat and doesn't move on to the next section, q2.

```
def q1(name):
    print
    q1= int(raw_input(
        """Question #1
Which of the following animals is native to New Zealand?
1) Possum
2) Rat
3) Tuatara
4) Sheep
Please enter your answer (1, 2, 3, 4)"""))
    while q1 not in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
        q1 = int(raw_input("choose 1, 2, 3 or 4."))

        if q1 == 1 :
            print
            print"That is an incorrect answer. The possum is a native species of Australia."
            W_A()
        elif q1 == 2 :
            print
            print"That is an incorrect answer. The rat arrived on ships, assumedly along with first human inhabitants of New Zealand."
            W_A()
        elif q1 == 3 :
            print
            print'Well done',name.title(),'. That is the correct answer. The tuatara is endemic to New Zealand, and due to its close relation to the dinosaurs that roamed millions of years ago, they are sometimes referred to as a "Living fossil".'
            R_A()
        elif q1 == 4 :
            print
            print 'That is an incorrect answer. Sheep arrived with immigrants from Europe in the 1800s for agricultural purposes. They were used to provide wool and meat for farmers.'
            W_A()
```

I'm curious to know why this is happening, and also what a simple fix would be. Your assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: You are parsing `raw_input` to `int` and expecting it to be within a list of `str` options?

Answer (score 6):

Your `q1` variable is an integer, but you're comparing it to strings in the condition. It's never going to be `True`.

```
>>> 1 == "1"
False
```

Replace your condition with `while q1 not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:`.

Comment: Hmm, when I do this it seems that it gets stuck when I give it a valid answer (1,2,3,4) and moves on to the next question without running any of the 'if' statements. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you enter a correct answer right off, it won't even enter your loop, of course. You'll have to dedent your `if`/`elif` blocks to be outside the loop.